# Module "Mixins" is not found in vue-chartjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js, vuejs3, vue-chartjs

I'm currently trying to import the `mixins` modules from vue-chartjs in order to use them. However, the program returns me a "not found" everytime i try it.
Here's the list of my import, who are in a <script setup>:

```
import 'chart.js/auto'
import { Chart, registerables, UpdateModeEnum, } from 'chart.js';
import { donnees } from '../../AfficheurDonnees.vue';
import { nextTick, ref } from 'vue';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  LineElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale
} from 'chart.js'
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs';
```

That last import doesn't work precisely because of the mixins.

Could anyone locate the problem with my imports?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have try to use this import VueChartJS from 'vue-chartjs'; const { reactiveProp, reactiveData } = VueChartJS.mixins; ?

Comment: what version of vue-chartjs?  [mixins were removed in v4](https://vue-chartjs.org/migration-guides/#new-reactivity-system)

Answer (score 0):

**Mixins have been removed after vue-chartjs version 3.**

v4 charts have data change watcher by default. v4 will update or re-render the chart if new data is passed that is why Mixins have been removed.

take a look at the [migration-guides](https://vue-chartjs.org/migration-guides/#new-reactivity-system) to know more.